# How to move from Mint 9 to Ubuntu 10.10?

Tags: upgrade, grub2, mint

1. I have a Mint 9 & Windows 7 laptop, that I, obviously, want to upgrade to Ubuntu 10.10.
   I do want to keep the dual boot, and I do not want to keep the Mint.
2. I have Burg controlling the boot - will that cause any problems with Ubuntu installation/Upgrade?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you run the Ubuntu installer, either off a cd or USB drive, there is an option in the partitioner to overwrite an existing Linux distro with the new one. That will leave your Windows installation alone while replacing Burg with Grub.

Answer (score 0):

1)

You could reformat the mint partition, then recreate the Windows boot loader bo going into the emergency recovery on your Windows CD.  Then install Ubuntu 10.10 and it will recreate the entries.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, answer the question to yourself: How was the Mint-Install done/initiated? 
(1) Out of a running Windows (I believe the Utility for that is called "Mint4Win"; Wubi is the equivalent in Ubuntu) 
OR
(2) after booting Mint as a live-CD.

That makes a big difference!

In case of (1), 
Save any valuable data out of Mint beforehand: Copy them from Mint to the Windows drive (should be seen / written to from within Mint).
Start windows and uninstall Mint: The uninstaller is in the Windows Program Menu or, at least, in the Mint setup directory (on the windows partition of course, you have to look for it). After that, install Ubuntu from within Windows (using Wubi), or from Live-CD (the latter required rearranging harddrive partitions, most likely shrinking Windows and adding Linux: root partition plus swap partition at least)

In case of (2), you may follow the solutions mentioned above.
Of course, answers 1 and 2 of our friends above imply that you are going to "nuke" your mint install rather than keep any data or settings.

If you want to keep your settings and data:
you may follow answer from Owais Lone (be careful -- I think it may NOT work though -- the dependencies between packages have not been tested that way by developers)

-- OR --

back up your /home and /opt - directories (the latter if it exists) and then follow answer 1 or 2.

TIP 
When nuking a distro, don't forget to think about valuables such as bookmarks or any personalized desktop settings. I for one have collected 200+ bookmarks easily - plus email settings and locally stored email plus RSS-feeds  - you name it, I got it over the years...

After the new install, copy the old /home and /opt into its original place, then login. If you use a different desktop now (say, KDE whereas you used to use Gnome), it will build default configs of what was not there before. But apps such as Mozilla or Thunderbird should now find most everything it had before (possibly reinstall of extensions and plugins necessary). Email (e.g. Thunderbird) should run perfect like there was no new install at all... it did in my case, many times already.

TIP2: 
A good bootloader when running Win7 or WinVista AND Ubuntu/Mint is EasyBCD, which is administered from Windows and is free.

TIP3:
Back-up before reinstalling operating systems  !!

TIP4:
Back-up before reinstalling operating systems  !!

TIP5:
Back-up before reinstalling operating systems  !!

Answer (score -1):

Try disabling all Mint repositories and enabling Ubuntu only repositories. Then issue this command
`update-manager -d`

I'm not sure about this. Just a guess.